# Filesystem becomes read-only in RHEL 5.1

Tags: linux, filesystems, permissions, redhat

I am working on RHEL 5.1 and the problem is that some partition goes read only and after rebooting it, it got corrected or running fsck manually on that partion.
Please do tell me why it goes read only and any log related to that where I can get help?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a corrupt file system.  Possibly caused by a failing hard disk.  Run the command 'dmesg', and see what the output says.  If your drive is failing, you will likely see a bunch of disk-related errors.  In that case, it's time to make an immediate backup of your data, then buy a new hard drive.

Comment: I also faced this issue many times. But hard disk was in  good state.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into single user mode by selecting your kernel and pressing e to edit and adding either 1, s, or single to the end of the statement.  Hit return and then press b to boot.  Once you are greeted with a prompt check your /etc/fstab to make sure root is readable.  The entry for root should look like this:

```
/ ext3 defaults 0 1
```

Additionally check to make sure your other partitions look sane.
If those look correct run dmesg to check that it isn't a hard drive problem.